# Load plugins own configurations.someConfig in Gradle

Tags: plugins, ant, gradle, classpath

I have a gradle plugin that calls some ant tasks.

I want to set the ant tasks classpath based on a configuration in the plugins's build file

My Plugin Build File (Not the project I want to build using the plugin) :

```
configurations {
    antTask1
}

dependencies {
    antTask1 'com.something:something:1.0'
}
```

I also have my ant task wrapped around a Gradle Task, and I want to reference antTask1

```
class MyTask extends DefaultTask {
    void executeTask() {
        ant.taskdef(name: 'antTask', classpath: **<WHAT GOES HERE?>**, classname: 'something') {
        ....
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this, I want the classpath of the anttask to include those dependencies from my build.gradle file (but not the rest of the compile/runtime dependencies)

I tried project.buildscript.configurations but that is referencing something else.  I understand if I define those dependencies in the project (that has applied the plugin) build file I can get to them easily, but is there a way to get a plugin's context and it's configuration when running tasks?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `project.configurations.antTask1.asPath` for that. The custom configuration is defined for your project's classpath, not for your build script's classpath. That's why you won't find it via `project.buildscript`. I'd recommend reading up on the difference in the Gradle online user guide.

Comment: project.configurations.antTask1.asPath only works if I put it in my project's build.gradle.  Is there to access the plugin's build.gradle configurations?